# usestate inside then or catch methods

Tags: reactjs

Please need your help  to solve the inline error

when I use the useBurgerState inside either in then or in catch methods I have the following error

> ESLint: React Hook "useBurgerState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

The following is the whole function:

```js
const BurgerBuilder = props => {
  const [BurgerState, useBurgerState] = useState({
    Ingredients: {
      salad: 0,
      meat: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      cheese: 0
    },
    price: 0,
    purchased: false,
    Modal: false,
    spinner: false
  });

  const ContinueHandler = () => {
    // alert('Continue!!')
    const order = {
      ingredients: { ...BurgerState.Ingredients },
      price: BurgerState.price
    };
    useBurgerState({
      Ingredients: BurgerState.Ingredients,
      price: BurgerState.price,
      purchased: BurgerState.purchased,
      Modal: BurgerState.Modal,
      spinner: true
    });

    instance
      .post("/orders.json", order)
      .then(response => {
        useBurgerState({
          Ingredients: BurgerState.Ingredients,
          price: BurgerState.price,
          purchased: BurgerState.purchased,
          Modal: false,
          spinner: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error =>
        useBurgerState({
          Ingredients: BurgerState.Ingredients,
          price: BurgerState.price,
          purchased: BurgerState.purchased,
          Modal: false,
          spinner: false
        })
      );
  };
  const ZeroIngredients = { ...BurgerState.Ingredients };
  for (let index in ZeroIngredients) {
    ZeroIngredients[index] = ZeroIngredients[index] <= 0;
  }
  let ModalHtml = null;
  let SpinnerHtml = (
    <OrderSummary
      price={BurgerState.price.toFixed(2)}
      clicked_D={ModalHandler}
      clicked_S={ContinueHandler}
      Ingredients={BurgerState.Ingredients}
    />
  );

  if (BurgerState.spinner) {
    SpinnerHtml = <Spinner />;
  }
  if (BurgerState.Modal) {
    ModalHtml = (
      <Modal click={ModalHandler} show={BurgerState.Modal}>
        {SpinnerHtml}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
  return (
    <WithClass>
      <Burger Ingredients={BurgerState.Ingredients} />

      {ModalHtml}

      <BuildControls
        add={AddIngredientsHandler}
        remove={RemoveIngredientsHandler}
        disabled={ZeroIngredients}
        price={BurgerState.price}
        purchased={BurgerState.purchased}
        Modal={ModalHandler}
      />
    </WithClass>
  );
};

export default BurgerBuilder;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of how you named your state setter, `useBurgerState`.

> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?** Please do. This
>   convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
>   automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
>   couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
>   it.

From [Using a Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

I know you're not creating a custom hook, but the naming convention you use says otherwise and the linter is flagging what it thinks is a hook being called within a nested function.

The standard convention for `useState` variables is the same for most variable naming conventions, camelCase. The exception here being the setter variable starts with a `set` prefix.

```
const [state, setState] = useState();
const [root, setRoot] = useState();
const [burgerState, setBurgerState] = useState();
```

This makes it easy to tell at a glance what is a `useState` hook setter.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**

Don’t call Hooks inside **loops**, **conditions**, or **nested functions**. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

(If you’re curious, please check official documentation) [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

You can call `setBurgerState()` inside `then()` like

```
axios
.post('/orders.json',order)
.then(res=> setBurgerState(res.data))
.catch(err=>console.log(err)
```

Comment: thank you, Vahid for your answer, but what is the difference between your code and mine